# Error java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin, sendgrid

I am using sendGrid APIs to send emails using sendGrid maven dependancy in our Java service.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

We create a fat jar of our service to execute it.
but after adding this dependancy, fat jar is not executing, giving SecurityException: Invalid signature file

Here's stack trace for the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:327)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:762)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1033)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:888)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:790)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:685)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, we need to filter signed file while creating a fat jar.
add filter in `maven-shade-plugin`

```
                   <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                     </configuration>
```